# Pass table of object type from java to oracle 8i

Tags: java, list, parameters, oracle8i

I need to pass a list of objects (like a table of values) from java to oracle 8i.

I am trying with the below database objects in oracle 8i.

Is this possible in 8i?
Please help me with a solution if possible.

```
create or replace type GROUP_OBJ as object    (          

 GROUP_TYPE VARCHAR2(32), 
 PARAM_1 VARCHAR2(16), 
 PARAM_2 VARCHAR2(16)
);
/


CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE GROUP_table AS TABLE OF GROUP_OBJ; 
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GROUP_TABLE_TEST (TABLE_OBJ IN GROUP_table)
IS

BEGIN
    null;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      ROLLBACK;
END GROUP_TABLE_TEST;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I was getting into trouble due to case sensitivity issue. the type name to pass into Structdescriptor and arraydescriptor is case sensitive. when gave the Upper case for both , it worked.

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;

public class PassTableOfObject {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
         Connection conn=FucntionTest.getConnection();

            try{

                StructDescriptor itemDescriptor = StructDescriptor
                        .createDescriptor("GROUP_OBJ", conn);

                STRUCT[] structs = new STRUCT[2];
                for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++)
                {

                    String[] params = new String[2];
                    params[0] = "Group "+index;
                    params[1] = "Param  1 "+index;
                    STRUCT struct = new STRUCT(itemDescriptor, conn, params);
                    structs[index] = struct;
                }

                ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("GROUP_TABLE", conn);
                ARRAY oracleArray = new ARRAY(desc, conn, structs);



                CallableStatement cs = null;
                cs = conn.prepareCall("{call GROUP_TABLE_TEST(?)}");
                cs.setArray(1, oracleArray);
                cs.execute();
                conn.commit();


                System.out.println("insert procedure executed successfully");                  

                }catch(SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();        
                }finally{
                    conn.close();
                }
      }
}
```